# How To Convert Sql to Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sql query like :-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
FROM [Customers] AS t0
WHERE NOT (LEN(t0.[ContactName]) > 0)
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [value]
```

Please let me know how I can convert to oracle query?
Thanks in advance.
Joon

Comment: On a sidenote: This is not "How To Convert **Sql** to Oracle Query", but "How to convert T-SQL to Oracle SQL", because T-SQL is also just some SQL dialect. The brackets `[]` are non-standard and `LEN` also isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, an empty string and `NULL` are identical so `LENGTH( NULL )` and `LENGTH( '' )` will both give `NULL` and not `0`.

So your query would be:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 
         FROM   Customers
         WHERE  ContactName IS NULL
       )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS value
FROM   DUAL
```

**Update**:

> What if I want to find out all records has length of contactname bigger than 3

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 
         FROM   Customers
         WHERE  LENGTH( ContactName ) <= 2
         OR     ContactName IS NULL
       )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS value
FROM   DUAL
```

or

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 
         FROM   Customers
         WHERE  COALESCE( LENGTH( ContactName ), 0 ) <= 2
       )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS value
FROM   DUAL
```

*Note: to use an index you will need a function-based index on `LENGTH( ContactName )` or `COALESCE( LENGTH( ContactName ), 0 )` for the respective examples.*

Comment: Why the downvotes? This answer seems correct to me and the query is very readable. (I'd turn this around to `WHEN EXISTS` though to speed this up a little.)

Comment: It works find but what if I want to find out all records has length of contactname bigger than 3 or like that. I thought your code is limited in in finding the record that has null only.

Comment: @JoonwK It is limited to finding non-null (0-length) strings because that is what you asked in your question. If you want strings of 3 characters or more then use `WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Customers WHERE LENGTH( ContactName ) > 3 )`.

Comment: @MT0: Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If your SQL checks "if there exists an empty contact name in the customers table" then you can use the oracle queries below.

```
SELECT DECODE(cnt, 0, 0, 1)
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) cnt
          FROM customers
         WHERE NOT NVL(LENGTH(contact_name), 0) > 0);
```

or

```
SELECT DECODE(cnt, 0, 0, 1)
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) cnt
          FROM customers
         WHERE contact_name IS NULL);
```

Comment: Look at the original query more closely. It is about whether there exists an empty contact name in the customers table. Both your queries are different from that.

Comment: thanks for the correction, modified my answer above.

Comment: In additon, you don't need the outer queries. I would also use a CASE expresssion instead of `DECODE()`, as this is clearer and easier to understand, particularly if the OP is used to CASE expressions in SQL Server.

Comment: yes, I agree with you but I'll keep my answer that way, it's up to the OP now what answer he will use in his problem. thanks anyway,

Answer (score 0):

to avoid null error use nvl function:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT NULL FROM Customers t0 WHERE NOT NVL(LENGTH(t0.ContactName),0) > 0
      ))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END val
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: @Joon w K: It's not an error actually. Look at MT0's answer. In Oracle an empty string and a null string are the same thing. Their length is null. This is something to be aware of. Paras' query does consider this, but so does MT0's query, which solves this even more elegantly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I got it like that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Customers  t0 WHERE NOT 
    LENGTH(t0.ContactName) > 0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END val
FROM DUAL
```

thanks all

Comment: `LENGTH( '' )` gives `NULL` not `0` and `NOT( NULL > 0)` is never true.